# Scala - how do I convert from DataFrame to Array[caseclass]

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I am using DataBricks to process data.

One of the columns in my DataFrame is an Array. I want to extract it so I can process it, but am having problems with the syntax. I seem to be extracting it still as a DataFrame and not converting to an Array

Here is an example. My data is a set of animals. Each animal has a name and a set of movements.

I define two Case Classes to hold the data

```
case class Movement ( 
  location: String,
  direction: String
)

case class Animal(
  var name: String,
  var movements: Array[Movement]
)
```

I define data for 2 animals, Gordon and David

```
val m1 = Movement( "farm1", "arrive");
val m2 = Movement( "farm1", "leave");
val m3 = Movement( "farm2", "arrive");
val m4 = Movement( "farm3", "arrive");

val am = Array( m1, m2, m3);
val am2 = Array( m1, m2, m4);
val df : Animal = Animal("Gordon", am )
val df2 : Animal = Animal( "David", am2 )
val df3 = Seq( df, df2 ).toDF;
```

I have a routine that processes movements. To simplify things, for this example it just displays them

```
def showMoves( amIn: Array[Movement]) {
  for( mv <- amIn ) (
    println( mv.location + " " + mv.direction )
  )
}
```

This works fine for Gordon and David's movements

```
showMoves( am )
showMoves( am2 )
```

And the results are:

```
farm1 arrive
farm1 leave
farm2 arrive

farm1 arrive
farm1 leave
farm3 arrive
```

This is the data all set up.

Now I decide I am only interested in Gordon, and want to extract his movements

```
val df4 = df3.filter( "name == 'Gordon'")
var am3 = df4.select("movements").as[Array[Movement]]
```

Scala tells me:

```
am3:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Array[Movement]] = [movements: array]
```

I now want to process his movements, and here is where the problem is.

```
showMoves( am3 )
```

Scala tells me this

```
command-721439694904705:44: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Array[Movement]]
 required: Array[Movement]
showMoves( am3 )
```

So I understand from this I have created am3 as a Dataset[Array[Movement]] instead of Array[Movement], but what I can't work out is how to create am3 in the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use collectAsList function to convert your dataframe to an array then map it to array of movement.
When you do that you collect all your data to the master node. So you can have oom error if data is heavy. 
So instead of

```
var am3 = df4.select("movements").as[Array[Movement]]
```

You should use

```
df4.select("movements").collectAsList()
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. When I tried:
`var am3  = df4.select("movements").collectAsList()`
Scala said the type was
`df4:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [name: string, movements: array]` 
and this gave the following error when calling
`showMoves( am3 )`

`command-721439694904705:47: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: Array[Movement]
showMoves( am3 )`

Comment: Apologies,  I couldn't find how to start a new line in mini markdown

Comment: you need to add .as[Movement] I think 
    df4.select("movements").as[Movement].collectAsList()
and Movement should be a case class